# Netty http server responses

Tags: http, netty

This is probably simple, but I couldn't figure it out. My Netty 4 based http server is causing http clients to hang on its response. It manages to send through its response payload (as observed using curl as a client) but the clients seem not to realize that the response has finished and they indefinitely wait for it to complete. Observed using curl, as well as firefox and chrome.

Only if I modify the code to close the channel (channel.close, as seen inline below), then do the clients acknowledge that the response is done. Otherwise, they just continue waiting for it to complete. I wish for the channel to stay open so that the next client request will not require opening a new connection (I wish to have keep-alive behavior), so closing the channel doesn't seem plausible. So I'm not sure how should the server mark the response as over - without closing the connection.

The server code:

```
val response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK)
val buf = new StringBuilder
buf.append("hello")
response.data.writeBytes(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(buf, CharsetUtil.UTF_8))
ctx.write(response).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener(){
  def operationComplete(channelFuture: ChannelFuture){
    if (channelFuture.isSuccess){
        println("server write finished successfully")
        //channelFuture.channel.close <===== if uncommented, clients receive the response, otherwise they just keep waiting forever
    }
    else 
        println ("server write failed: " + channelFuture.cause + "\n" + channelFuture.cause.getStackTraceString)
  }
})
```

What am I missing??

Comment: Are you sending a Content-Length header?

Comment: Not really, I'm not actively adding any headers. Should I?

Comment: Yes. Without the Content-Length header, your client doesn't know when to stop reading. If your content is just "hello", then add: Content-Length: 5.

Comment: Thanks. Was a bit naive thinking writeBytes would take care of that.... Isn't there some other way of using Netty API to compose response data while simultaneously taking care of both content and length? isn't the response's data length managed transparently somewhere in the API? I'm new to Netty

Comment: No, there isn't. I have helper classes to do it, but that's something you need to handle on your own.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Care to turn this into an answer so I can mark it as your answer? or if you don't care I'll 'Answer My Own Question' to close it off. Off topic: I may be pursuing other ways than netty + http for my server, as I don't want to go into low level programming for accomplishing mere obvious outcomes if this was any indication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a Content-Length header, or else the client won't know when to stop reading, and will continually poll for more data.